# Export dynamic CSS as text

Tags: javascript

I am creating a [CSSStyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet) in javascript. I want to then export the style sheet css as text.

Is there a function/way to get the CSS text from a `CSSStyleSheet`? The following returns an empty string:

```
$('<style id="mystyle"></style>')
  .attr('type', 'text/css')
  .insertBefore(this.element);

$('#mystyle')[0].sheet.insertRule('#mydiv {color: red;}', 1);

console.log($('#mystyle').html()); // should show '#mydiv {color: red;}'
console.log($('#mystyle').text());
console.log($('#mystyle')[0].innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CSSStyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) object your are working with provides you with `cssRules` (instance of [CSSRuleList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRuleList)) property which is an array like object you can iterate over to extract all necessary `cssText` strings.

For example of aggregation of all cssTexts into one string with [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
$('<style id="mystyle"></style>')
  .attr('type', 'text/css')
  .appendTo(document.body);

const styleSheet = $('#mystyle')[0].sheet

styleSheet.insertRule('#mydiv {color: red;}');
styleSheet.insertRule('p {color: green;}');

// second argument to insertRule is not needed in our case, but your could do
// styleSheet.insertRule('#mydiv {color: red;}', styleSheet.cssRules.length);

const cssText = Array.from(styleSheet.cssRules).reduce((prev, cssRule) => {
  return prev + '\n' + cssRule.cssText
}, '')

console.log(cssText)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mydiv">one</div>
<p>two</p>
```